# Set default group for user when they create new files?

Tags: permissions, users

I often find myself chown-ing files as I created them through SSH and they are owned by `jm:jm` for example.

Then to allow Apache to access it, I need to for example do `chown jm:www-data`.

I am sure I can specify that when I create files, instead of using the group under my name, specify another?

Or is there a better way of managing users/groups?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

If you want all new files in a particular directory to be owned by a particular group, just apply the `setgid` bit on it:

```
chgrp www-data /some/dir
chmod g+s /some/dir
```

If you have an existing tree of directories that you want to apply this behaviour to, you can do so with `find`:

```
find /some/dir -type d -exec chgrp www-data {} +
find /some/dir -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +
```

(if the directories are already owned by the relevant group, then you can omit the first command in both of these examples).

Comment: Nice answer! Could you, please clarify what do the symbols `... {} +` mean?

Comment: They are arguments to the `find` command, covered in the man page.  For the first invocation, it will run the command `chgrp www-data`, appending a number of results as arguments (rather than invoking the command once for each result as you'd get with `{} \;`).

Comment: Why not use `chmod g+s /some/dir -R`? Just tested and it seems to work.

Comment: @Cragmonkey: that will also set the setgid bit on regular files.  If any of them happen to be executable, this would allow another user on the system to gain the privileges of the group that owns the file.